# Why components written within switch case would not be shown in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to develop a dynamic tab, when clicking on a tab I want a specific component be shown. But, components are not working :(

My Tab component:

```
function Tabs () {
const project = (text) => {
    switch(text) {

      case "Special Price":   return <TabPane id="SpecialPrice" text={text} />;
      case "New Product":   return <TabPane id="NewProduct" text={text} />;
      case "Best Seller": return <TabPane id="BestSeller" text={text} />;

      default:      return <h1>No section match</h1>
    }
  }

  return(
    <>
        <ul className="nav nav-pills tabs" role="tablist">
            {
                tabItems?.map((item) => {
                    return(
                        <div key={uuid()} className="tabItems">
                                <li className="nav-item" onClick={() => project(item.text)}> 
                                    <a href={item.ref} className="nav-link" data-toggle="pill"> {item.text} </a>
                                </li>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </ul>
    </>
);
}
```

My Tabpane component:

```
function TabPane ({id, text}){
return(
    <div className="tab-content">
        <div id={id} className="tab-pane" >
            {text}
        </div>
    </div>
);
}
```

Comment: The default in switch is return ?

Comment: yea, is it wrong?

Comment: you need to `console.log(text)` because switch statement cases doesn't match with provided value.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how?

Answer (score 0):

```
const project = (text) => {
  console.log('text', text);
  console.log('type of text', typeof text);
  // what if text is undefined or null. In switch statement it going to be run default case everytime.
  // Or if text is in lowercase e.g. "text= special price" switch cases doesn't match with them.
  switch (text) {
    case 'Special Price':
      return <TabPane id="SpecialPrice" text={text} />;
    case 'New Product':
      return <TabPane id="NewProduct" text={text} />;
    case 'Best Seller':
      return <TabPane id="BestSeller" text={text} />;

    default:
      return <h1>No section match</h1>;
  }
};
```

Comment: I did this and the value and its type were returned correctly, but still components won't be shown

Comment: can you share a codesandbox link so i can checkout your code

Comment: I have found out that the problem is with tab-content. I can see its div in inspet element but not on the page